# AngularJS and Node.js Express - $http.get Success Block Not Being Called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm very new to `AngualarJS` and `Node.js`, and I have a problem with my `$http.get` method's success callback block not being executed. When the request fails, my error callback block works, but when it succeeds, nothing happens.

This is what I have in my `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// This is for testing GET connection with server
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   console.log("Got a GET request from my angular app");
   res.send('Hello ANGULAR');
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

This is what I have in my `app.js`:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8081/test")
  .success (function (response) {
    alert("GOT A RESPONSE");
  })
  .error (function() {
    alert("SERVER GET TEST FAILED THO");
  });
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try removing the server variable and just using `app.listen(8081);`

Comment: Uncomment the line where you're sending the response to your browser:  `// res.send('Hello ANGULAR');` -> uncomment this

Comment: After uncommenting that line and your success callback works fine (i.e. it's called) please also remove this question entirely. :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to uncomment that line. This still hasn't been working for me whether I sent a response or not. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server's `app.get` block is missing a response sending :

Try adding :
`res.sendStatus(200);`
or `res.status(XXX).send(*object/string*);`
at the end.

Here's the documentation : http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res

Comment: When I uncomment the `res.send` command then my errorcallback is called.

Answer (score 0):

The angular and node.js code look fine. But there could be any number of problems between network, configuration, etc.

The best way to figure this out is to use Chrome Dev tools network panel. Click "Inspect" on your page or Command-ALT-i (Mac).

Click the "network" panel tab to see your request and the response received.

Comment: e.g. you may think it is a successful request and it is not.

Comment: this answer is nothing more than a comment how to do basic debugging. Use comment blocks for that

Comment: Maybe basic debugging is all Rafi needs.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8081/test').then(
    function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("ok")
    },
    function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("error") ;
    }
);
```

According to the official documentation, don't use success :

**Deprecation Notice**

The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Comment: why downvote ??? The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated.

Comment: You overthinked the solution... :) The OP simply forgot to send the response from nodeJs side. p.s. I didn't downvoted your answer.

Comment: `try this` doesn't explain why there would be any difference. Deprecated doesn't mean removed

Comment: Sorry but for me there is a huge difference between `$http.get().success ().error ()` vs  `$http.get().then()`.  'Deprecated doesn't mean removed' . maybe it will be removed on next update and all his work will not work. anyway if he get it work it's good

Comment: I didn't downvote, but while your answer is true and good advice for the OP it doesn't actually answer the question. I think you should have made it a comment rather than an answer.